# How does copy-on-write work with read-only virtual pages in mmap function?

Tags: linux, c, virtual-memory

I'm new to C and Linux, just a question on the usage of `mmap` function, the function prototype of `mmap` is

`void *mmap(void *start, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);`

and  I saw code like this:

```
char *srcp = mmap(0, filesize, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, srcfd, 0);
```

and we know that `PROT_READ` means the virtual pages can be read only.
and `MAP_PRIVATE` indiacates it is a private copy-on-write object. copy-on-write technique is sth like, when two processes uses the same object, when process A modify the object, those changes belong to process A only and invisible to process B. so `MAP_PRIVATE` allow users to write sth, but `PROT_READ` indicates read-only, since we can only read it, there is no meanning to use COW(to use COW,you need to be able to write sth first then COW will make the change only visible for your process),  are't them contradicting to each other?

Comment: Multiply posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/64310192/340790 by prolific multi-poster account [amjad](https://stackexchange.com/users/13332616/amjad) (another of whose multiple-posting accounts is [slowjams](https://stackexchange.com/users/15559049/slowjams)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `mmap`, the caller must choose between a shared (`MAP_SHARED`) or private (`MAP_PRIVATE`) mapping. The use of copy-on-write is an implementation detail; compare with [the POSIX definition of `mmap`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html).

The type of mapping (shared or private) only determines what happens to writes. Thus with `PROT_READ`, it doesn’t matter, and the use of copy-on-write doesn’t either. Any change made to the backing file will ultimately be visible in the process’ mapping, even with a private mapping. In theory, this behaviour could change:

> Updates to the mapping are not visible to other processes mapping the same file, and are not carried through to the underlying file.  It is unspecified whether changes made to the file after the `mmap()` call are visible in the mapped region.

(from [the `MAP_PRIVATE` description in `man 2 mmap`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)).

Note too that a process can change the memory protection with [`mprotect`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html), assuming it is able to write to the underlying file. The type of mapping can’t be changed, but the protection can, so a process can map a file read-only, then change to read-write (if the file itself was opened read-write); copy-on-write becomes relevant then.

(Thanks to [user414777](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/414777/user414777) for correcting a number of errors in previous versions of this answer. Any remaining errors are my own.)

Comment: sorry, still confused, if process A maps an area as private copy on write,  that doesn't stop process B from wrting it, process B has to call `mmap` with `MAP_PRIVATE`. My confusion is, process A can only read the virual pages, why it set the mapping to be `MAP_PRIVATE` when itself cannot actually write on it

Comment: I think you got it wrong way around. Process A uses `mmap` with `MAP_PRIVATE ` because when process A writes, it doesn't want other process B to see the change it made. and if you check the man page, it says "(to the process who uses `MAP_PRIVATE `, e.g. process A)Updates to the mapping are not visible to other processes(e.g. process B) mapping the same file"

Comment: Forget about COW. The first question to ask when using `mmap` is “do I want a shared mapping, or a private mapping?” *Everything else* is secondary, including whether the process will read or write, and whether the kernel will use COW.

Comment: "Process A sets the mapping to `MAP_PRIVATE` ... With a private mapping, other processes can’t write to the pages in a way process A can see" That is *at least* horribly confusing. If process A calls `mmap(.., MAP_PRIVATE, ...)` to mmap the file `foo.txt`, and then another process B *writes* to `foo.txt` (no matter how it's doing it), process A will immediately see the changes made to the file. `MAP_PRIVATE` means that the modifications process A does to memory won't be carried through to the file, not that process A will have its private copy of the file.

Comment: That being said, I cannot make any sense neither of the question nor of the answer. But it's probably just me.

Comment: @user414777 yes, it’s confusing, and I didn’t want to go into details there — “It is unspecified whether changes made to the file after the `mmap()` call are visible in the mapped region.” (in the `MAP_PRIVATE` description in the `mmap` manpage).

Comment: @StephenKitt that "unspecified" is an allowance for when Hurd will be ready and ruling the world. Just test it. Try to overwrite a shared library, see your program crash. (`ld.so` uses `mmap(MAP_PRIVATE)` to map it in the process's memory; by overwrite I mean the same file/inode, not create replace it with another file with the same name).

Comment: @user414777 without overwriting libraries, even two processes mapping the same file, and only one making changes to it (without `msync` or `munmap` are enough to show illustrate the behaviour. Thanks for the clarifications!

Comment: @user414777  yes I was thinking the exactly same as you,  "If process A calls mmap(.., MAP_PRIVATE, ...) to mmap the file foo.txt, and then another process B writes to foo.txt , process A will immediately see the changes made to the file. But I don't know why the process A also use `PROT_READ` with `MAP_PRIVATE`. `PROT_READ` means process A cannot write but only read, while  `MAP_PRIVATE` means if process A write sth, it will be only private to A itself, why you want to specific sth that you cannot do?

Comment: @StephenKitt I saw you edit your answer and mentioned that "Thus with PROT_READ, it doesn’t matter, and the use of copy-on-write doesn’t either." do you mean when using `PROT_READ`, COW has no meanning in the context? why do we still have to specific a value as an argument `MAP_PRIVATE`, can we use `NULL` to replace `MAP_PRIVATE`?I mean C should be smart and have a mechanism to catch this logic flaw.

Comment: You still need to specify private or shared because `mmap` doesn’t know, when it’s called, that you won’t call `mprotect` to change the protection at some point in the future.